# Is Blender 2.81 able to pack Animated Textures?

Tags: texturing

I want to be able to pack like a .mp4 as an image texture, but last time I did this in 2.8, it wasn't possible. Is it a feature yet in the lastest update?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html):

> Not all external files can be packed
>
> Some typically heavy external files, like video ones from the Sequence Editor or Movie Clips, cannot be packed in a blend-file.

Consider what would happen if you did pack those files in. Every time Blender makes a backup save (which it does by default), it'd have to make a copy of all the data, including the video files. If you're considering uploading your project to a render farm, some allow for video files to be sent in an accompanying zip file.

If you're just transferring the file from computer to computer, consider using *Relative Paths* and keeping all your files in organized folders.

Comment: Note that image sequences and simulation caches won't be packed either.